# What's this Java generic syntax in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am new to Java. I just see the following code in the Spring framework. It looks like some kind of generic code. But what does the leading `<T>` mean?

```
<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `getBean` method has a generic type parameter. That's the way to define generic methods (where the generic type parameter is not part of the class definition).